# What is the oldest work to incorporate an acrostic of shem Havaya in the opening?

Tags: history, jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names, provenance, acronyms

I have seen many books where the first letters of the first 4 works in the first sentence of the work spell out the shem Havaya (the Tetragrammaton, yud-kay and vav kay). What was the first Jewish book that made use of this?

Comment: something tells me this comes from the end of bereshis 1:31 into 2:1 which we recite in kiddush.

Answer (score 1):

We'll go with [Double AA's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51358/what-is-the-oldest-work-to-incorporate-an-acrostic-of-shem-havaya-in-the-opening?atw=1#comment136187_51358) Mishne Torah for now.

[Rambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides)'s [Mishneh Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah) was compiled, according to Wikipedia, " between 1170 and 1180 (4930–4940)."

It begins ([Yesodei HaTorah 1:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=1&halocha=1)) "**י**סוד **ה**יסודות **ו**עמוד **ה**חכמות."

Comment: If anyone knows of any earlier book, please post an answer, and leave me a comment! I'm curious :)

Comment: Do you have any evidence that usage was intentional? It is not highlighted in any old manuscript I can find.

Comment: @DoubleAA, what would constitute evidence?

Comment: @Yishai Lots of things could be evidence? The simplest of course is Rambam writing so in a letter or something. You could also look towards old manuscripts, translators notes or even classial commentaries

Comment: @DoubleAA [חזון נחום](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21238&st=&pgnum=8&hilite=) makes the point, FWIW.